# Plotting a Radar drawing with matplotlib not working correctly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I found this resource:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-stunning-radar-charts-with-python-implemented-in-matplotlib-and-plotly-91e21801d8ca

And I am trying to create my own version where I will analyze emotions for a free text survey.  Instead of 5 categories, I will have 7 emotions:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


categories = ['Joy', 'Fear', 'Anger', 'Sadness', 'Disgust', 'Shame','Guilt']

q1 = [4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 10]
q2 = [5, 5, 4, 5, 2,9,2]
q3 = [3, 4, 5, 3, 5,10,2]
q4 = [3, 4, 5, 3, 5,8,8]

label_loc = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2 * np.pi, num=len(q1))

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(polar=True)
plt.plot(label_loc, q1, label='q 1')
plt.plot(label_loc, q2, label='q 2')
plt.plot(label_loc, q3, label='q 3')
plt.plot(label_loc, q4, label='q 4')
plt.title('Answer to Question 1 - Emotion Analysis', size=20)
lines, labels = plt.thetagrids(np.degrees(label_loc), labels=categories)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

However the Joy and Guilt emotions are overlapping in the drawing.
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: `num=len(q1)+1`, presumably?

Comment: Actually: `label_loc = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2*np.pi, num=len(q1)+1)[:-1]`

Comment: thanks! how come that it works on the original resource?

Comment: it works, but the last line on the radar between guilt and joy is not there, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the original source code is correct. This produces the desired output:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

categories = ['Joy', 'Fear', 'Anger', 'Sadness', 'Disgust', 'Shame','Guilt']

q1 = [4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 10]
q2 = [5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 9, 2]
q3 = [3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 10, 2]
q4 = [3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 8, 8]

label_loc = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2*np.pi, num=len(q1)+1)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(polar=True)
for q in [q1, q2, q3, q4]:
    plt.plot(label_loc, np.r_[q, q[0]], label='q 1')
plt.title('Answer to Question 1 - Emotion Analysis', size=20)
lines, labels = plt.thetagrids(np.degrees(label_loc), labels=categories)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get the same result but with an ugly error in the console:  The number of FixedLocator locations (8), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (7)

Comment: Weird, my version doesn't. It's probably complaining about the extra point in `label_loc` when constructing the grid. Does `lines, labels = plt.thetagrids(np.degrees(label_loc[:-1]), labels=categories)` remove the warning?

Comment: yes ! that removes the warning! thanks a lot

Comment: what does this part means?  np.r_[q, q[0]]

Comment: It concatenates each series with its first entry to close the loop. I could also have written `np.concatenate([q, [q[0]])`.